# Why the light beside of repository shown as yellow in Xcode4 Organizer?

Tags: version-control, repository, xcode4

In Xcode4 Organizer, a light icon beside of source code repository name is shown as yellow for specific one. Other are shown as green. What does yellow means? I feel something wrong, but I can't know what's wrong.

Comment: I've got the same issue - this happened after I moved my Xcode project folder elsewhere when I was re-organising my directories.  The git repo seems to be fine - no problems on the command line or in the tower application, just Xcode giving me a yellow icon which I'm also not sure of what it means.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968715/yellow-indicator-on-git-repository-under-xcode-4 edit: just recognized its the other way around :)