# Yellow Indicator on Git Repository under Xcode 4

Tags: git, xcode4

I used to use Subversion for my source control in Xcode 4.  Increasingly, I have been having problems with it.  Since Xcode now supports Git, I thought I would try that.

It seems to be set up and working, but I'm a little concerned about something.  Under Organizer -> Repositories, it shows a Git Repository for each project.  However, the indicator light on the right side of the Repository name is Yellow.  I can find no documentation about this and can't seem to fix it.  The samples on Apple's User Guide show the indicators are Green (see below).  But, on mine they are Yellow.

Is this something to be concerned about?  How do I fix it?  Do I need to completely uninstall SVN?

FYI, I have tried the following:

1. Have removed all .SVN directories from my projects.
2. Have moved the SVN repository to another location because it kept showing up in Organizer.

Any help is appreciated!

[image: This shows the indicators are green.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is just cosmetic.  Apple answered my question in the developer forums.  They indicated that you can ignore the status light for Git repositories.  If it is Red, however, it is probably because the repository doesn't exist.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/431507#431507