# What do the colored icons in Xcodes' Orginizer Repository denote?

Tags: git, xcode4

In Xcode4's Organizer Repository some of the icons can be different colors. What do they denote. For example what does this yellow dot mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to mean the connection to the repository is having some issues like authentication needed, but in case of Git, I suppose you can ignore it. Also have a look at the answer here: [Yellow Indicator on Git Repository under Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968715/yellow-indicator-on-git-repository-under-xcode-4/5990640#5990640)